# xclip check if "selection" is empty

Tags: bash, xclip

As an FYI this is on Linux.

I want to have one of the options in a script to be to pull the selected text. So I start my script

```
#!/bin/bash

xclip -o > ~/bin/temp.txt
```

However, if I don't have anything selected this throws the error

```
./test
Error: target STRING not available
```

Can I check whether something is selected and skip this command if there isn't?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about xclip, but how about something like:

`myclip=$(xclip -o)
if [ -n "$myclip" ]; then
  echo $myclip > ~/bin/temp.txt
fi`

If `$myclip` is unset or has zero length (=`""`), nothing will be written to `temp.txt`.

Comment: It must be an xclip error. This still produces the error.

Comment: if you issue `myclip=$(xclip -o) && echo $myclip`, what is the result?

Comment: It pastes whatever is in any of my clipboards. If it's empty (ie I copy a blank) it has the error. If I have something, it pastes that.